# sow the seeds for (whence definite article? )

Tags: articles, metaphors

I have a quote from an [article](http://www.economist.com/news/leaders/21582008-hamid-karzai-and-barack-obama-should-stop-playing-games-afghanistans-future-why-zero-not) in The Economist:

> But they could re-establish a grip on large parts of the south and
>   east of the country, give succour to al-Qaeda, and sow **the** seeds for a
>   new civil war.

Please explain why we need to put the definite article before "seeds": it seems to be a generic reference, and so either "the seed" or "seeds" seems to be OK. There's no particular species of seeds that lead to civil war, a civil war may be caused by all kinds of "seeds" in the metaphorical sense; so why "the"? Do we need the THE because it is idiomatic usage in this case?

Comment: It's not that you "need" the definite article here - just that idiomatically most people probably *would* use it. Interestingly though, Google Books has 6 instances of [sow seeds for a future war](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22sow+seeds+for+a+future+war%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), but only 4 instances of [sow **the** seeds for a future war](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22sow+the+seeds+for+a+future+war%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Comment: Oh, very interesting! Variation is possible after all. Thanks, FumbleFingers!

Comment: @ CopperKettle: Those figures are too low to be statistically significant. But *sow [the] seeds of unrest* returns 140 [414] results, which more convincingly shows that both versions exist. I don't think there's any semantic distinction which can be meaningfully "explained". What normally happens is you tend to use the version you hear more often - which may or may not become so firmly established that eventually almost everyone agrees that any alternatives are simply "wrong". But things haven't gone that far with this one (yet! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's idiomatic: "sow the seeds" basically means to lay down the catalyst for a future result.

Answer (score -1):

> civil war may be caused by all kinds of "seeds"

Perhaps the metaphor used within the article is based upon the notion that there will be multiple separate seeds which will grow to form this civil war (there are large arrays of militia groups operating within the Middle East [Syria a prime example]) but each will operating under a the shared agenda of al-Qaeda's goals? Just a thought.

Comment: -1 Mere speculation. See answer from @GnoveltyGnome.